# PHPExcel using Ajax to download file on Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, excel, wordpress, phpexcel

I am making a report on Wordpress where i am using PhpExcel to make an excel file and download it. I am doing this by using Ajax. The problem with this is that when i get the response, the popup window doesn't display and hence can't download the file.

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {poll_id: _id, action: 'admin_poll_by_id'},
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(rs) {
        alert('Report generated');
    }    
});
```

I can guarantee that the excel file is being generated because it returns a 200 response, and displays some weird characters on chrome networks response. This is my php code before the exit.

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $fileName . '"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: saving the object to php://output is just like trying to print it in the screen. then you're returning that as response (that's where the weird characters come from. It would be easier to just write a fixed file (overwritting it everytime the report is needed) and then throw back the download link.

Comment: @LordNeo great suggestion, any suggestions on how to save to the uploads dir? (this would be the best place to save it right?)

Comment: Just use any directory, maybe even the one where the script resides. the save function lets you specify the route where you want it saved.

Comment: @LordNeo thanks for the help, saved me a lot of time, was about to change all of it to make a post call, thanks again